# Why am I suddenly getting ImagePullPolicy errors?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Using GKE

Trying to deploy a yml that has a docker image that contains `gcr.io/myproject-101/pyftp`. I have not had a problem with pulling this image at all until just recently. And from the looks of it it just started happening after my trial ran out. I've tried recreating my cluster and directly getting the path from the container registry.

```
Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/myproject-101/pyftp" BackOff Jul 14, 2018, 3:49:29 AM    Jul 14, 2018, 3:59:27 AM    41
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/myproject-101/pyftp": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error pulling image configuration: unknown blob Failed  Jul 14, 2018, 3:49:28 AM    Jul 14, 2018, 3:51:02 AM    4
```

I keep reading that it has to due with coming from private repos...but nothing has changed. They're all within my one project. Pull have worked before. Only thing that I can think of that I have done recently is start to make use of "cookies" since I had to to hook my github desktop application into the private repo. To do this I was linked to a page that provided me commands to run to push to that repo. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Are you sure that image exists? Do you have an image tagged `latest` in your GCR repo?

Comment: I had it tagged with a build hash that the autobuilder added at first. The build before it was marked as latest. I tried removing that build hash and then moving latest to the highest one before this post thinking the same thing. Same issue.

Comment: Nevermind! It never saved. And I get an `Could not update tags` error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using default settings, builds are required to be tagged as latest. Using default auto-build settings for container builder, it lets the tag as the commit's hash rather than the `latest` tag.